# Hyphenation of a name

Tags: punctuation

How would I punctuate this sentence: "She wanted the red one but Patty-the-nurse nixed that idea." I've already introduced Patty as a character before this sentence. Is hyphen ok? I want to make it humorous instead of "Patty, the nurse,..."

Comment: If the story is seen through the eyes of a character who thinks of Patty in that way, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

It would be fine if there was another Patty, as in *Patty-the-nurse looked at Patty-the-policewoman*. Otherwise it seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Patty-the-nurse is in no way wrong, nor in any way useful.

As with any other stylistic tool if you have a doubt about it, don't use it.

Answer (score -2):

Why not Nurse Patty? A little bit derogatory, a little cute

Comment: You should also consider the question about appropriateness of the hyphen,as posed by OP.